# I parse 104 feeds but get to display only 20?

Tags: android

So, I am parsing RSS feeds of a podcast that I like. There are about 100 `<item>` tags and I know that they are all parsed properly as I log each tag that I parse.

However, when there is the final call to display the list using `ArrayAdapter` in the `onPostExecute` of the `AsyncTask`, I only get about 20 feeds. I have no clue why.

I changed the initialization of the `Vector` that stores all the feed objects to have an initial size of 120 in which case the app stops working all together. Out of memory I presume.

How do I make sure that I get all my 120 feeds ??

*I know one way would be to lazy load the feeds rather than eager load. How do I keep track of scrolling then (the direction, how many views to load, etc)?*

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(FeedProcessor p){
            pDialog.dismiss();
            ListView list = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.expandingList);

            if(p.errorOccured == false){
                feeds = p.getFeeds(); // populate the list

                ArrayAdapter<Feed> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Feed>(getActivity(),
                        R.layout.list_row,
                        R.id.row,
                        feeds);
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
            }else{
                Log.d("Error", "Error");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what do you see in the list? do you see all the data?

Comment: What does .getFeeds method do (code)?

Comment: @Juan It just returns a `Vector<Feed>`. `p` is an object of a custom class named `FeedProcessor` that extends `org.xml.sax.DefaultHandler` :)

Comment: Show us code of getFeeds(); :)

Comment: @LittleChild: is there any server config which returns 20 feeds at a time?

Comment: @anuja no. Like I said, I log all the tags I parse. so I k now all 120 feeds are parsed.

Comment: @alex `return allProcessedFeeds` where `allProcessedfeeds` is also a `Vector<Feed>` :) Basically, I am just visualizing the vector as a list

Comment: If you debug your code, after calling `p.getFeeds();`, how many entries does your `Vector<Feed> feeds` have?

Comment: @LittleChild:ok..so you mean to say that your vector has all the 120 records, but they are not getting displayed in the list view?

Comment: @Terry ok, wait for sometime as the feeds take a lot of time to process :)

Comment: @Terry Alright .. somewhere buried deep in the code was a conditional  statement that caused this error. Apparently I put it there for testing.. :) Sorry for the inconvenience caused

Comment: Cool. Wanna give my comment a vote up then? Would be great :)

Comment: @Terry give my question a +1 so it does not have a -1 xD